# How to disable a widget in Kivy?

Tags: python, user-interface, widget, kivy

I read the Kivy tutorial and couldn't find how to disable a widget (for example, a Button).

```
def foo(self, instance, *args):
  #... main business logic, and then
  instance.disable = False
  # type(instance) = kivy.uix.Button
```

I bind `foo` with `functools.partial`.

What is the correct parameter?

Answer (score 19):

If you are using kivy version >= 1.8 then you can just do widget.disabled = True. If on previous versions you can simply manage the disabling yourself, just make sure it doesn't react to touch and displays a alternative look when disabled.

Answer (score 18):

1. It's `disabled`, not `disable`
2. Set it to True

Example:

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App
from functools import partial

class ButtonTestApp(App):
    def foo(self, instance, *args):
        instance.disabled = True

    def build(self):
        btn = Button()
        btn.bind(on_press=partial(self.foo, btn));
        return btn

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ButtonTestApp().run()
```

Comment: I added
    `def foo(self, instance, *args):
        print instance.disabled
        instance.disabled = True`

and got 
_print  instance.disabled
 AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'disabled'_

Comment: `disabled` property was introduced in version 1.8.0. If you want to use it you need to actualize your framework.

Comment: But how? [In the official site](http://kivy.org/#download) was wrote that "The current version is 1.7.2, released on Aug 4th, 2013." Where did you get the new one))?

Comment: Newest version is a dev one. You can find it on GitHub project page: https://github.com/kivy/kivy

Answer (score 7):

In the following example `MyButton` follows @qua-non idea. It uses a `BooleanProperty` to change the `background_color` and `color` of it. More important, it adds a condition `if self.enabled:` in the `on_touch_down`. If there is no `on_touch_down`, then there is no `on_touch_move`, `on_touch_up`, `on_press` or `on_release`. Therefore, we can consider the `Button` disabled.

I use the name `enabled` instead of `disabled` to avoid possible future problems with by using the same attribute of Kivy 1.8.0.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
<Example>:
    cols: 3
    Button:
        text: "Disable right button"
        on_press: my_button.enabled = False
    Button:
        text: "enabled right button"
        on_press: my_button.enabled = True
    MyButton:
        id: my_button
        text: "My button"
        on_press: print "It is enabled"
""")

class MyButton(Button):
    enabled = BooleanProperty(True)

    def on_enabled(self, instance, value):
        if value:
            self.background_color = [1,1,1,1]
            self.color = [1,1,1,1]
        else:
            self.background_color = [1,1,1,.3]
            self.color = [1,1,1,.5]

    def on_touch_down( self, touch ):
        if self.enabled:
            return super(self.__class__, self).on_touch_down(touch)

class Example(GridLayout):    
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Example()

if __name__=="__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```